# How do I create shadow of CPBarPlot?

Tags: iphone, ipad, core-plot

I want to create shadow of barplot what should I do . I use core-plot framwork

Comment: Is your question about shadow effect of a bar?

Answer (score 0):

I dont know abt giving exactly shadow effect on individual bar. But similar to shadow effect, You can try using 'tubular' bar rather than flat bars. +(CPBarPlot *)tubularBarPlotWithColor:(CPColor *)color horizontalBars:(BOOL)horizontal

something like this

barPlot = [CPBarPlot tubularBarPlotWithColor:[CPColor greenColor] horizontalBars:NO];
[barGraph addPlot:barPlot toPlotSpace:barPlotSpace];

Hope this helps.